# why is python xlsxwriter data validation not working in microsoft office excel?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, ms-office, xlsxwriter

I wrote data validation drop down code with the help of python xlsxwriter. But the drop down validation is not accepted by Microsoft Excel. It was working with libreoffice and google docs. MS Office is the only not supported. Here's the data validation issue thrown by MS Office
[image]

I uploaded data validation issue from ms office..

Comment: Show a small complete working example that creates a file that raises this error. It is impossible to tell what the issues is otherwise. Although a common error is to have overlapping validation ranges.